# Nginx Too Many Redirect - Wordpress Container Reverse Proxy

Tags: wordpress, nginx, nginx-reverse-proxy

I am trying to reverse proxy a wordpress containerized app. I've turned off the proxy of cloudflare and make them act as DNS only. here is my nginx conf file:

```
server {
    root /var/www/html;
    listen 443 ssl;
    listen [::]:443 ssl;
    server_name [redacted].us www.[redacted].us;
    location / {
        proxy_pass         http://127.0.0.1:81/;
        proxy_redirect     off;
        #proxy_set_header   Host localhost:81;
        proxy_set_header   Host $http_host;
        proxy_set_header   X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
        proxy_set_header   X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
        proxy_set_header   X-Forwarded-Host $server_name;
        proxy_set_header   X-Forwarded-Proto $scheme;
    }

    ssl_certificate /etc/letsencrypt/live/[redacted].us/fullchain.pem; # managed by Certbot
    ssl_certificate_key /etc/letsencrypt/live/[redacted].us/privkey.pem;
 # managed by Certbot



}

server {
    if ($host = www.[redacted].us) {
        return 301 https://$host$request_uri;
    } # managed by Certbot


    if ($host = [redacted].us) {
        return 301 https://$host$request_uri;
    } # managed by Certbot


    listen 80;
    #listen [::]:80;
    server_name [redacted].us www.[redacted].us;
    return 404; # managed by Certbot
}
```

If proxy set header is change to the one that is commented the infinite redirect is resolve but every link inside is broken. I use certbot to auto renew the ssl certificate and I believe i leaving the default configuration file as default. Any work around because I can't even open the Admin panel yet to see how wordpress handle the request